# Store Sql Function Value in string

Tags: c#, sql

[image]

I have function in SQL as above, i want the value 'INTERNATIONAL' stored in the string(**'strIntlStudent'**). How can i accomplish that? I know data reader but column has no name.

```
string TSQL_INTERNATIONAL = "select TOP 1  campus6.dbo.fndqgetpopulation_of_YT_v2a ('P000170620', '2017', '03TERM')";
DataTable DT_INTERNATIONAL = dhelper.ExecuteSelectCommand(TSQL_INTERNATIONAL, CommandType.Text);
if (DT_INTERNATIONAL != null && DT_INTERNATIONAL.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    strIntlStudent =  DT_INTERNATIONAL.Rows[0]["it says no column name"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is the code of campus6.dbo.fndqgetpopulation? Did you try to add an alias to the result returned by that function?

Comment: I have no access to the code, i can just view it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give your column a name. Try this:

```
select TOP 1  campus6.dbo.fndqgetpopulation_of_YT_v2a
              ('P000170620', '2017', '03TERM') AS some_name
```

Then you can use that name:

```
strIntlStudent = DT_INTERNATIONAL.Rows[0]["some_name"].ToString();
```

Alternatively, if you are only retrieving one value, then you can use `ExecuteScalar` function which returns one value regardless of the column name and you don't need to bother with a table. Check your `dhelper` class to see if it has a function related to `ExecuteScalar`.